# how do i reslove The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null. while signinig out from app?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

getting this warnings/error  while signing out  though my app runs fine but the warning appears every time how can i resolve it thank you

this is the error/warnings
ignore this(jdjdjdjcjjjdidjieneijfiicjcnksmakoekruhfrnkcmoosjmnnzciodufdksjmcxzkidbhshdjdsjabjsbdjbsjbdjbdbfhfbshfbhfbfdhbjzjanjdbhbfcsjnxjhdhbxjdzxndjxbcnjdhnjajkjksjakjskjsakjxmksjcmdx)

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter (15815): Receiver: null
E/flutter (15815): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
E/flutter (15815): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (15815): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2179:40)
E/flutter (15815): #2      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1645:22)
E/flutter (15815): #3      _HomePageState.checkAuthentification.<anonymous closure> (package:authentification/HomePage.dart:24:18)
```

here is my code

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  bool isloggedin = false;

  checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "start");
      }
    });
  }

  getUser() async {
    User firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser;
    await firebaseUser?.reload();
    firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      setState(() {
        this.user = firebaseUser;
        this.isloggedin = true;
      });
    }
  }

  signOut() async {
    _auth.signOut();

    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentification();
    this.getUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: !isloggedin
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("images/welcome.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hello ${user.displayName} you are Logged in as ${user.email}",
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                  onPressed: signOut,
                  child: Text('Signout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```html
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      title: 'FlutterChat',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
       
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, builder: (ctx, userSnapShot){
        if(userSnapShot.hasData){
          return HomeScreen();
        }
        return AuthScreen();
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code to help other people understand it.

Comment: sir its not working same error occurs on terminal while logingout